# How to make a call to one file, with dependencies on the original file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wasn't sure how to title this, or if this will even make sense. But, here we go.

I have file A which contains an object. I want to be able to create a modular command system, which would mean I need file B to house the commands. I need to be able to determine which command to process in file A. File b needs to execute the code, but still use the same object.

How can I accomplish this?

File A:

```
var obj = { functions... }
command.process(command)
```

File B:

```
var commands = {
    name: 'help',
    run: function(cmd) {
        obj.sendMessage("help is on the way!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is how to set up a cyclic dependency between two node modules. Such a dependency structure might be a [bad code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), and you should try to avoid it, but you can still do it. Here's an example loosely based on your code:

a.js

```
const b = require('./b');

Object.assign(module.exports, {
    sendMessage: function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }
});

b.commands[0].run();
```

b.js

```
const a = require('./a');

module.exports.commands = [{
    name: 'help',
    run: function() {
        a.sendMessage('help is on the way!');
    }
}]
```

Output:

```
node a.js
help is on the way!
```